# What is the difference between intrinsic and monitor locks in java?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

Could someone explain the difference if any between these terms?

Comment: According to http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/locksync.html, they are synonyms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

intrinsic and monitor are synonyms.